# how do i use find, nm, and grep to find a symbol among many shared libraries?

Tags: bash, grep, find, nm

I'm struggling with the right command to do the following:

find all shared libraries (*.so) that contain a certain symbol.

This is what I've tried:

```
find -iname '*.so*' -exec nm {} \; | grep -H _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
```

The above gives some output with symbols found, but doesn't pinpoint the filename that the symbol occurred in.  Any flag that I give to grep to tell it to print a filename is lost because grep is being fed from stdin.

```
(standard input):         U _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
(standard input):         U _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
(standard input):         U _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
(standard input):         U _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
(standard input):0015e928 T _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
(standard input):         U _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
(standard input):         U _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
(standard input):         U _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
```

Another attempt:

```
find -iname '*.so*' -exec nm {} \; -exec grep _ZN6QDebugD1Ev {} \;
```

This doesn't work because the two execs are completely independent.

What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass the "-A" option to nm which will prefix its output with the filename.  Then just grep for the symbol you're interested in, for example:

```
find -iname '*.so*' -exec nm -A {} \; | grep _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
```

Comment: plus 1.  For greater efficiency, on systems that support it, replace `\;` with `+`.

Comment: Nice one @John1024 - I'm going to have to remember that!